# Customizing web deploy publish procedure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msdeploy, web-deployment-project, microsoft-web-deploy

I'm investigating the powerful of WebDeploy based on Scott Hanselman's [post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx). I was using Web Setup Project before, and trying to find an analog for Custom Actions in Web Deploy.

Generally, is there a place in WebDeploy procedure I could integrate into, and execute some particular c# code that could perform some install/upgrade actions?

Comment: I don't think that there is such generic functionality but what are you trying to accomplish? With more details I might be able to suggest something.

Comment: for example - a custom/complex db update (which includes some c# logic, so can't be written in plain sql)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the command-line version of Web Deploy, you can leverage the **runCommand** provider or the **preSync** or **postSync** command line switches to run an executable on the destination server as part of a Web Deploy operation. For more information, see my answer to the StackOverflow question [Use MSDeploy to copy an executable to a server and to then run same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552692/use-msdeploy-to-copy-an-executable-to-a-server-and-to-then-run-same).